# IE8+ JQuery Ajax sub domain calls and ovveriding response Response

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, cross-domain

I'm having some trouble with IE and Ajax calls for IE browsers 8 and up. I have a site that does ajax calls to a subdomain which returns json data. For IE8 I found and added this ovveride for Ajax calls, code below:

```
if ('XDomainRequest' in window && window.XDomainRequest !== null) {
  // override default jQuery transport
  jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
      try { return new XDomainRequest(); }
      catch(e) { 
        console.log(e); 
      }
  };

  // also, override the support check
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
  jQuery.ajaxSettings.dataType = 'json';

}
```

The problem is the response, which does not come back as json but plain text. How can I fix this globally for all Ajax calls?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the jQuery AJAX parameter "dataType" to "json", this tells it that you want a JavaScript JSON object back rather than letting it make an intelligent guess based on the response mime-type.

If that doesn't work I suppose you could try adding a custom converter for plain-text that runs the response through a JSON parser.